# How do I implement a pull to refresh in WinJS and embed it in a XAML webview?

Tags: xaml, winjs

I am looking to implement a pull to refresh in WinJs and then embed this in a XAML Webview. Any sample code will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you found any ways to do this yet?  I'm looking to do something similar.